# Conditional Probabilities on Coin Toss

Tags: probability

Was having some trouble understanding the last step of the solution where it was determined where the two expressions for $P(F_{n,m})$ were equivalent, specifically:

> $ P(F_{n,m}) = \frac{1}{6} P(F_{n-1,m}) + \frac{1}{2} P(F_{n,m-1}) + \frac{1}{3} P(F_{n,m}) $ 
>  
>   $ P(F_{n,m}) = \frac{1}{4} P(F_{n-1,m}) + \frac{3}{4} P(F_{n,m-1})   $

Apologies for the alignment issues in the two images, if anyone can edit to make it clearer, it would be really helpful.

---

[image]

Comment: Note that you have $P(F_{n,m})$ on both sides of the first equation. It looks like the author just subtracted $1/3 P(F_{n,m})$ from both sides, then multiplied by $3/2$.

Comment: I didn't even catch that. That took unnecessarily long to spot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first equation:

$$\begin{array}{lrll}
&P(F_{n,m}) &= \tfrac{1}{6} P(F_{n-1,m}) + \tfrac{1}{2} P(F_{n,m-1}) + \tfrac{1}{3} P(F_{n,m}) \\[1ex]
\implies & \tfrac{2}{3}P(F_{n,m}) &= \tfrac{1}{6} P(F_{n-1,m}) + \tfrac{1}{2} P(F_{n,m-1}) &(\text{rearranging}) \\[1ex]
\implies & P(F_{n,m}) &= \tfrac{1}{4} P(F_{n-1,m}) + \tfrac{3}{4} P(F_{n,m-1}) &(\text{multiply through by }\tfrac{3}{2}) \\
\end{array}$$

Note that the first equation arises from the fact that for two dice, out of the $36$ possible rolls there are $6$ for which the sum is seven, $18$ for which the sum is even, and $12$ for which the sum is neither seven nor even.